# Table Adapters namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, tableadapter

I'm in Visual Studio trying to use a table adapter (from a xsd file in the App_Code folder). I've tried remaking it multiple times with various different names too.

For example, I currently have "PleaseWork.xsd" in my App_Code folder. In the codebehind for a page I've got using `PleaseWorkTableAdapters;` at the top. It's telling me the namespace could not be found for some reason.

[image: Screenshot of error in Visual Studio]

Checked the actual code for the xsd file too and it's got this at the top so the name I used should be correct

```
<xs:schema id="PleaseWork" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various restarts of Visual Studio, cache deleting, and other things, updating ReSharper from 2017.1.3 to 2017.2 is what fixed the problem.